# Explanation of specific part in a diagram

Tags: pointers, clojure

[image: Clojure]

I understand everything besides the last line. More specifically the (:x y) part. Why is pointing to 10? Also just to be sure... is the first element in y supposed to be pointing to the whole thing (10 and 20) or just the 20? Thank you!

Comment: This is ambiguous without the definition of `Double`. Is the first slot in `Double` called `x`?

Comment: Whence comes this diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In clojure, symbols with `:` as a prefix are [keywords](http://grimoire.arrdem.com/1.6.0/clojure.core/keyword). [Official docs](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Keywords). Keywords when used as functions have almost the same behavior as [get](http://grimoire.arrdem.com/1.6.0/clojure.core/get). So the intention of `(:x y)` is `(get y :x)`.

If we assume that there's a `(deftype Double [x y])` in your program that doesn't appear in this image, this means in your last form the second element of your Tripple type is the field `:x` or `.x` of the Double `y`, being just the value `(Double. 10, 20)`. You can test this at a REPL if you want...

```
user> (defrecord MyDouble [x y])
user.MyDouble
user> (defrecord MyTripple [x y z])
user.MyTripple
user> (def x (MyDouble. 10 20))
#'user/x
user> (def y (MyDouble. x 40))
#'user/y
user> (def z (MyTripple. x (:x y) y))
#'user/z
user> z
#user.MyTripple{:x #user.MyDouble{:x 10, :y 20}, :y #user.MyDouble{:x 10, :y 20}, :z #user.MyDouble{:x #user.MyDouble{:x 10, :y 20}, :y 40}}
user> (:x y)
#user.MyDouble{:x 10, :y 20}
```

Answer (score 1):

The diagram is thoroughly confusing.

`x` is used for two distinct things:

- the symbol for a record of type `Double` and
- the name of a field of type `Double`.

Assuming that `x` is the name of the *first* field of `Double`, given

```
(def y (MyDouble. x 40))
```

then

```
(def z (Triple. x (:x y) y))
```

... is equivalent to

```
(def z (Triple. x x y))
```

Hence the *two* arrows pointing to `Double{:x 10, :y 20}`, the value of the global `x` (assuming the other field is named `y`).

And it is seldom helpful to consider these references as pointers. Records, like almost all the basic data structures in Clojure (only [`deftype`s](http://clojure.org/datatypes) spring to mind as an exception), are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

**It's Shared Structure!**

```lisp
(defrecord MyDouble [x y]) ;; (defrecord Double [x y]) produces an exception
(defrecord Triple [a b c])
(def x (MyDouble. 10 20))
```

This creates a new `MyDouble` record with the values `10` and `20`. `(:x x)` => 10, `(:y x)` => 20.

```lisp
(def y (MyDouble. x 40))
```

This creates a new `MyDouble` record. Its first value is the value that `x` has at that moment, which is `#user.MyDouble{:x 10, :y 30}`. and `40`. That is, `y` has the value: `#user.MyDouble{:x #user.MyDouble{:x 10, :y 20}, :y 40}`.

```lisp
(def z (Triple. x (:x y) y))
```

This creates a new `Triple`. object. Just as with the previous line, the first value is `#user.MyDouble{:x 10, :y 30}`. The second value is the value of the expression `(:x y)`:

```lisp
user=> (:x #user.MyDouble{:x #user.MyDouble{:x 10, :y 20}, :y 40})
#user.MyDouble{:x 10, :y 20}
```

So the second value is also `#user.MyDouble{:x 10, :y 20}`. The third value is the value of `y`, or `#user.MyDouble{:x #user.MyDouble{:x 10, :y 20}, :y 40}`.

So `z`, printed out, is:

```lisp
#user.Triple{:a #user.Mydouble{:x 10, :y 20}, 
             :b #user.Mydouble{:x 10, :y 20},
             :c #user.Mydouble{:x #user.Mydouble{:x 10, :y 20}, 
                               :y 40}}
```

What the diagram is showing you is that there is a lot of shared structure here. The `#user.Mydouble{:x 10, :y 20},` you see repeated three times in `z` is, in fact, the exact same object, not three copies. And so yes, in answer to your last question, the arrow is pointing to the whole thing, not just to the number 20.